# Is there any good tutorial on how to set up vhosts using MAMP on a MAC?

Tags: .htaccess, mamp, vhosts

After searching online and not finding a good tutorial on how to do this, I got it working and this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to httpd.conf on your MAMP directory and uncomment this line `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. Go to httpd-vhosts.conf and add your virtual hosts like so: 
   `<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/yoursite"
   ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>` do this for each site or virtual host.
3. Restart MAMP

That works for most of us but if you have problems then:

1. Turn off your MACs Apache `sudo apachectl stop`
2. Clear your browser's cache or use incognito mode
3. If the urls are not working go to httpd.config and change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride all`